# Web Api c# Post usando 2 clases

Tags: c#, .net, post, backend, webapi

Estoy trabado en el desarrollo de una web, del lado del back c#.

Estoy intentando ingresar datos de un botonazo a 2 tablas distintas, pero, relacionadas entre si

```
       Venta Producto
       public int IdVentProd { get; set; } (autonumerico)
       public int? IdVenta { get; set; }
       public int? IdProducto { get; set; }
       public int? Cantidad { get; set; }
       public decimal? Precio { get; set; }
```

```
    Venta
    public int IdVenta { get; set; } (autonumerico)
    public int? IdCliente { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Fecha { get; set; } (Datetime.now)
```

Necesitaria crear el post para ingresar desde el front, estos datos, entiendo que tengo que crear una tercer clase, para poder usar 1 unico argumento y crear el httppost, pero no se la forma de juntar 2 clases en un post...

```
Venta producto
idventa relacionado a venta
idproducto relacionado a otra tabla productos
cantidad
precio

Venta
Fecha(datetime.now)
idcliente
```

Comment: Agrega el metodo para sugerir cambios, que herramienta estas usando para probar el web api,

Comment: Siguiendo la lógica de una venta, yo lo que haría seria a la clase venta agregar una propiedad Productos de tipo List<Venta Producto>,  y así solo recibo el objeto venta con los productos dentro.